# Everything submitted to Flask Form is a string, which always fails form validation

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to get a basic Flask Form set up, but realizing that everything I submit to the form is read in as a string:

```
from flask import blueprints, render_template
from flask import request
from wtforms import Form, DecimalField,
from wtforms.validators import NumberRange
    class PredictionForm(Form):
        inputfield = DecimalField("Impressions", validators=[NumberRange(min=0.0, max=1.0, message="Not valid")
        anotherinput = DecimalField('View Rate', validators=[NumberRange(min=0.0, max=1.0, message="Not valid")])

    @blueprint.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
    def index():
        form = PredictionForm()
        print(request.form)
        print(form.validate()) # this always returns False!
        if request.method == "POST":
            print(request.form)
```

When I print `requests.form`, I get the following output:
`ImmutableMultiDict([('inputfield', '0'), ('anotherinput', '0.5'))])`

I think this is why my form validation continually returns false, since clearly any value that is a string is not a number between 0 and 1. How do I get Flask to recognize my input values as numbers?

If this is NOT the reason why my validation is failing, please do let me know as well.

Note: I am printing `request.form` to debug - so I can see what type of data is being passed into my form. I know I can clearly validate on the server-side, by doing something like

input_field = request.form['input_field']
if input_field.isnumber():
  ... some more logic

However, all of this is happening on the backend server-side. The whole point of using these Flask validators is that I DON'T need to do this validation server-side. For instance, if I change my validation for a field called `spend`:

```
 class PredictionForm(Form):
        inputfield = DecimalField("Impressions", validators=[NumberRange(min=0.0, max=1.0, message="Not valid")
        anotherinput = DecimalField('View Rate', validators=[NumberRange(min=0.0, max=1.0, message="Not valid")])
        spend = DecimalField('Spend', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

This works perfectly on my frontend, since if I attempt to submit my form with no input for spend, I get this message:
[image]

Comment: can you add the error logs?

Comment: @Reactive_learner there are no error logs - I've printed what I can from the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my issue - I am not passing in the `request.form` to my `PredictionForm` instantiation:

```
@blueprint.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
    form = PredictionForm(request.form)
    form.validate() # this validates correctly now!
```

On the frontend, if the user does not enter a valid number for the `Decimal` value, he/she will get an error message.

Answer (score 1):

Am just confused in what you are trying to achieve. why do you print **request.form**
if you want to pass form parameters eg email, phone_no to flask you can do this

```
email = request.form['email']
phone_no = request.form['phone_no']
```

If you wants to validate for instance **phone_no** as no
You can do

```
if not phone_no.isdigit():
    print ("phone no must be numbers")
```

so your code for sending form parameters eg for **email and phone_no** will look like. you can perform other checks along down
the code

```
  @blueprint.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
    def index():
        form = PredictionForm()
        print(request.form)
        print(form.validate()) # this always returns False!
        if request.method == "POST":
            print(request.form)

            email = request.form['email']
            phone_no = request.form['phone_no']
```

**Updated section of my answer:**

if you are valiadting for numbers, it should be integerfield.  Also check to ensure that the field is also interer in your model

```
IntegerField('Telephone', [validators.NumberRange(min=0, max=10)]
```

see documentations [link](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FormField)

Comment: I am printing `request.form` for debug purposes, so I can see what type of data is being passed through to my POST endpoint. Your method works, but it defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do. Flask has validators that are supposed to handle this validation on the frontend - validating the form responses on the backend (server-side) is obviously an option, but not what I am looking for.

Comment: I've updated my question to include more examples that might be more helpful for an answer.

Comment: On the front end, its better to use javascript or jquery/ajax. or some kind of plugin. 
The way you are going about it in your code is backend validations and not front end

For server-side validation for form you can also check WTForms library, that contains some classes of pre-defined validators.
https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I have seen a typo error in your code I have updated my answer Please see the update section of my answer and let me know how it goes.

Comment: The typo was me just typing up an example quickly on SO - sorry! I actually just figured it out - see my answer above.